# how to insert json multidimension array data into database

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [catalog] => Array
        (
            [book] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [-id] => bk101
                            [author] => Gambardella, Matthew
                            [title] => XML Developer's Guide
                            [genre] => Computer
                            [price] => 44.95
                            [publish_date] => 2000-10-01
                            [description] => An in-depth look at
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [-id] => bk102
                            [author] => Ralls, Kim
                            [title] => Midnight Rain
                            [genre] => Fantasy
                            [price] => 5.95
                            [publish_date] => 2000-12-16
                            [description] => A former arc
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [-id] => bk103
                            [author] => Corets, Eva
                            [title] => Maeve Ascendant
                            [genre] => Fantasy
                            [price] => 5.95
                            [publish_date] => 2000-11-17
                            [description] => A former arc
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [-id] => bk104
                            [author] => Corets, Eva
                            [title] => Oberon's Legacy
                            [genre] => Fantasy
                            [price] => 5.95
                            [publish_date] => 2001-03-10
                            [description] => A former arc
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [-id] => bk105
                            [author] => Corets, Eva
                            [title] => The Sundered Grail
                            [genre] => Fantasy
                            [price] => 5.95
                            [publish_date] => 2001-09-10
                            [description] => A former arc
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [-id] => bk106
                            [author] => Randall, Cynthia
                            [title] => Lover Birds
                            [genre] => Romance
                            [price] => 4.95
                            [publish_date] => 2000-09-02
                            [description] => A former arc
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [-id] => bk107
                            [author] => Thurman, Paula
                            [title] => Splish Splash
                            [genre] => Romance
                            [price] => 4.95
                            [publish_date] => 2000-11-02
                            [description] => A former arc
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [-id] => bk108
                            [author] => Knorr, Stefan
                            [title] => Creepy Crawlies
                            [genre] => Horror
                            [price] => 4.95
                            [publish_date] => 2000-12-06
                            [description] => A former arc
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [-id] => bk109
                            [author] => Kress, Peter
                            [title] => Paradox Lost
                            [genre] => Science Fiction
                            [price] => 6.95
                            [publish_date] => 2000-11-02
                            [description] => A former arc
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [-id] => bk110
                            [author] => O'Brien, Tim
                            [title] => Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible
                            [genre] => Computer
                            [price] => 36.95
                            [publish_date] => 2000-12-09
                            [description] => A former arc
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [-id] => bk111
                            [author] => O'Brien, Tim
                            [title] => MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide
                            [genre] => Computer
                            [price] => 36.95
                            [publish_date] => 2000-12-01
                            [description] => A former arc
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [-id] => bk112
                            [author] => Galos, Mike
                            [title] => Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide
                            [genre] => Computer
                            [price] => 49.95
                            [publish_date] => 2001-04-16
                            [description] => A former arc
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

the PHP code:

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("shiv", $con); 
$jsondata = file_get_contents('example.json'); 
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true); echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($data); echo '<pre>'; 
$sql = "insert into book values('','','','','','','','')"; 
?>
```

Comment: add your code also in question

Comment: how do you want to insert it? as a json object in one table field ?!

Comment: please show us your code what you've actually tried so far and what your problem is. otherwise, general "how to" questions are better suited for [search engine of your choice] than for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @ChetanAmeta Sir there is an array above this page , i want to insert that data into database using php.i am new in php.i am confused how to grab all the data from 3d array.

Comment: @Mohammad Sir just , i want to insert that data(array data) into database using php.i am new in php.i am confused how to grab all the data from 3d array.

Comment: Did you create your database table already?

Comment: i just want to grab all the data from this array , i could not able to grab all data into variable , after i want to insert it into database

Comment: I believe we all understand what it is that you are trying to achieve, @ShivRoy. What we don't know is what you have coded/done/tried so far. Please update your question to include your efforts.

Comment: @ShivRoy so, in another way, you are asking about how to get data from json array? please share us your php code it would help us understanding your issue.

Comment: <?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("shiv", $con);

    $jsondata = file_get_contents('example.json');
    

    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
  echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
  echo '<pre>';  

  $sql = "insert into book values('','','','','','','','')"; 

?>

Comment: as i said , i am new here.i want to make variable for each data like id, author,title ,.. that will contain all the data from this array , after that i will use that variable to insert into database

Comment: how to get all the data from this array?

Comment: @ShivRoy thats another question. after decoding the json it will be converted to stdClass object, so you can access the data by this way for ex: `$data->catalog->book[0]->author;`

Comment: @Mohammad , Sir $data->catalog->book[0]->author; this will give me single data of author .i want to get all the array data mybe using foreach loop ,  i could not do this ...so plz help me out sir

Comment: how to fetch  data from this array using foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($data->catalog->book as $book){

     $someVar = $book->author;
     ...
}
```

Comment: Actually there is one more array after book ..